# android Picture.createFromStream does not reload bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

On android I am drawing into a android.graphics.Picture then save the Picture to a file. Later I reload the picture into memory and draw it to the canvas. I noticed that Bitmaps were never drawing. And after much debugging I managed to narrow down the problem to Picture.writeToStream and Picture.createFromStream. It seems that Bitmaps drawn into the picture don't get reloaded properly. Below is sample code I wrote to show the problem. In this sample my canvas is not hardware accelerated.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is this an Android bug? I filed the bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54896 because I think this is.
3. Any known workaround?

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
   {
       try
       {
           Picture picture = new Picture();

           // Create a bitmap
           Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( 100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
           Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
           bitmapCanvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);

           // Draw the bitmap to the picture's canvas.
           Canvas pictureCanvas = picture.beginRecording(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

           RectF dstRect = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 200);
           pictureCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, null);

           picture.endRecording();

           // Save the Picture to a file.
           File file = File.createTempFile("cache", ".pic");
           FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
           picture.writeToStream(os);
           os.close();

           // Read the picture back in
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
           Picture cachedPicture = Picture.createFromStream(in);

           // Draw the cached picture to the view's canvas. This won't draw the bitmap!
           canvas.drawPicture(cachedPicture);

           // Uncomment the following line to see that Drawing the Picture without reloading 
           // it from disk works fine.
           //canvas.drawPicture(picture);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find an answer to this question after looking at the native android code that backs the Bitmap. Android only can only save certain types of bitmaps to the picture. This is because the SkBitmap class only supports certain types of inputs that result in a bitmap that can be saved to a Picture. So in this can I can workaround the problem by providing those magical inputs. Use a bitmap that is saved to disk and call BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor to create it.

```
private Bitmap createReusableBitmap(Bitmap inBitmap)
{
    Bitmap reuseableBitmap = null;

    if (inBitmap== null)
        return null;

    try
    {
        // The caller is responsible for deleting the file.
        File tmpBitmapFile = File.createTempFile("bitmap", ".png");

        setBitmapPath(tmpBitmapFile.getAbsolutePath());

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmpBitmapFile);
        boolean compressed = inBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();

        if (compressed)
        {
            // Have to create a purgeable bitmap b/c that is the only kind that works right when drawing into a 
            // Picture. After digging through the android source I found decodeFileDescriptor will create the one we need.          
            // See https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp
            // In short we have to give the options inPurgeable=true inInputShareable=true and call decodeFileDescriptor

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            options.inScaled = false;
            options.inMutable = false;
            options.inTempStorage = DraftRenderer.tempStorage; 

            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(tmpBitmapFile);
            FileDescriptor fd = inStream.getFD();
            reuseableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
            inStream.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return reuseableBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: a picture created from an input stream cannot be replayed on a hardware accelerated canvas.
[Picture.createFromStream(InputStream stream)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html#createFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

you can use canvas.isHardwareAccelerated() to detect hardware accelerated or not.

Comment: Yes I know about that. I said "In this sample my canvas is not hardware accelerated."